# Is it possible to use image method from HtmlHelper to get images from the files directory in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have an upload helper that uploads files to a specific directory in files such as `webroot/files/images/upload/{id}`. Is it possible to use the image method of htmlhelper to get these files?

Now I'm using this piece of code to retrieve them, but it hurts my eyes everytime I see it:

`<img src="<?php echo Helper::webroot('files/image/upload/' . $image['dir'] . '/' . $image['upload']); ?>" />`

Is it possible or is it bad practise to upload images to the files directory anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you just missed starting the path with "/" in your original example.

`echo $this->Html->image('/files/image/upload/' . $image['dir'] . '/' . $image['upload']);`

Comment: I'll use this since it's shorter (you'll have to remove the last closing parenthesis, else it will throw an illegal character exception)

Answer (score 0):

After some searching in the source, it turns out it is possible, you'll have to set the `pathPrefix` option

Like this:

`<?php echo $this->Html->image($image['upload'], array('pathPrefix' => 'files/image/upload/' . $image['dir'] . '/')); ?>`